# Classes and inheritance qt

Tags: c++, qt, class, inheritance

I have 2 classes:

.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
QMainWindow(parent) {
}
...
Inheritor:Inheritor(QWidget *parent):
MainWindow(parent) {
...
}
```

.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
  QWidget *centralWidget;
public:
  MainWindow (QWidget* parent=0);
  QwtPlot *funPlot;
}
  class Inheritor : public MainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
  QWidget *centralWidget;
public:
  Inheritor (QWidget* parent=0);
...
}
```

Is that right realization? I have a segmentation fault. And I think it's here. I use varaible funPlot which declared in MainWindow class. Maybe my inheritance is wrong. Can you help me please?

```
void Inheritor::setCheckBox() {
    first_b = new QCheckBox("option 1");
    second_b = new QCheckBox("option 2");
    third_b = new QCheckBox("option 3");
    fourth_b = new QCheckBox("option 4");
    QPushButton *drawButton = new QPushButton("Draw");
    QVBoxLayout *rightLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    rightLayout->addWidget(first_b);
    rightLayout->addWidget(second_b);
    rightLayout->addWidget(third_b);
    rightLayout->addWidget(fourth_b);
    rightLayout->addWidget(drawButton);
    rightLayout->addStretch();
    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(funPlot);
    mainLayout->addLayout(rightLayout);
    QWidget *cent = new QWidget();
    cent->setLayout(mainLayout);
    setCentralWidget(cent);

    resize(640,480);
    connect(first_b, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addPoints()));
    connect(second_b, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addPoints()));
    connect(third_b, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addPoints()));
    connect(fourth_b, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addPoints()));
    drawButton->setCheckable(true);
    connect(drawButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(drawCurve()));
}
```

Comment: Seg fault can be due to many things. Please isolate the problem in a minimal, complete and verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then post it (including all cpp and header files), your post does not show all code, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Is that right realization? Answer is YES. But there must be something wrong in your code.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thanks

Comment: I thought it was a mistake here, because when I commented the method everything is OK, and with it, an error occurs.

Comment: If `funPlot` is not initalized and this functions uses it, the function causes the seg fault, but the problem is in `MainWindow::MainWindow` because `funPlot` was not initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`funPlot` pointer was not allocated.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent) 
{
    funPlot = new QwtPlot( this );
}
```

If not allocated, program will most likely seg fault when `funPlot`is being used (like in `Inheritor::setCheckBox` when you do `mainLayout->addWidget(funPlot);`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped!